# Date Limitation of Low Fares in Far East

Tags: air-travel, tokyo, fares, low-cost-carriers, seoul

I'm looking to travel from Tokyo to Seoul and have found a number of airlines that fly the route (or similar) and offer reasonable prices. However, these prices do not extend to my desired travel date.

To anyone who knows the market, is it usual to have to wait until a couple of months before the flight to book and get a good deal? In Europe the rule of thumb is that the earlier you book, the cheaper the ticket!

Comment: You might want to have a look at star allience's asia airpass (https://www.staralliance.com/en/fares/airpasses/asia-airpass) or oneworld's Visit asia pass (http://www.oneworld.com/flights/single-continent-fares/visit-asia) You can get some pretty cheap flight deals with that.

Comment: In Europe in my experience, the rule of thumb is that, except on beach routes, the best price is about 6 weeks before hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is usual, at least in Japan. Note that even in Europe you can't book *too* early.

Although regular airlines such as JAL and ANA operate on a similar schedule than other international airlines (*i.e.*, tickets go on sale about a year in advance) for international routes, low-cost airlines operate on a tighter schedule. For example, Summer 2015 tickets at [Peach](http://www.flypeach.com/home.aspx) went on sale [on 9 December 2014](http://www.flypeach.com/Portals/0/PressReleases/2014/141209-Press-Release-E.pdf), so you couldn't have booked them a year in advance like on regular airlines.